# About `page_table_lock` in Linux process address space

Tags: linux, kernel, process-management, lock

I'm reading a tutorial about [Linux page table](https://notes.shichao.io/lkd/ch15/#translation-lookaside-buffer), in the linked page

> Each process has its own page tables (threads share them). The `pgd` field of the memory descriptor points to the process's page global directory. **Manipulating and traversing page tables requires the `page_table_lock`**, which is located inside the associated memory descriptor.

So what is a `page_table_lock`? Is it some kind of reader-writer lock to prevent race condition?

Comment: read [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/split_page_table_lock) - it used to be a spin lock (simple mutual exclusion - no read-writer), but it is now more complicated.